# discord.js how to limit the clear command under 14 days without throwing any error

Tags: discord.js

Can someone show how to evade clearing messages that under 14 days
example : if clear command purge 50 msgs but there's only 20 msgs that under 14 days i need to purge only the 20 msgs even without putting a number

````
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    let command = message.content.split(' ')[0];
    const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
    const deleteCount = parseInt(args[0], 10);
    command = command.slice(prefix.length);
    if(command === 'clear') {
        message.delete();
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('```You don\'t have the permission```').then(mes => mes.delete(3000)) .catch();
        const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: deleteCount });
        message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
        const messagesDeleted = fetched.array().length;
        message.channel.send('```php\n' + messagesDeleted + ' messages have been deleted\n```').then(mes => mes.delete(3000)) .catch();
    }
});
````

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first i didn't know that i can user `(deleteCount, true)` to active filterOld . But now it worked well for me after using this code :

````
    if(command === 'clear') {
        message.delete();
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('```You don\'t have the permission```').then(mes => mes.delete(3000)) .catch();
        const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit:deleteCount }, true);
        const msgsDeleted = await message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched, true);
        message.channel.send('```php\n' + msgsDeleted.size + ' messages have been deleted\n```').then(mes => mes.delete(3000)) .catch();
    }
});
````

Answer (score 0):

To catch any error that occurs, do `message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched).catch(console.error);`.

This will catch any errors that occur.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) that `channel.bulkDelete()` accepts a second argument, `filterOld`, which should be a boolean indicating whether the function should automatically filter out messages that are older than 2 weeks to avoid an error by Discord.

You can also simplify your command by making use of the fact that `bulkDelete()` can accept a number instead of a collection of messages, so you don't have to manually fetch the messages to delete. It resolves with a collection of the messages that were actually deleted, so you can return the size of this collection to your user.

Something like this should work better:

````
    if(command === 'clear') {
        message.delete();
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('```You don\'t have the permission```').then(mes => mes.delete(3000)) .catch();
        const messagesDeleted = await message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteCount, true);
        message.channel.send('```php\n' + messagesDeleted.size + ' messages have been deleted\n```').then(mes => mes.delete(3000)).catch();
    }
````